# Why does clipping take place after illumination?

Tags: graphics, rendering, pipeline, clipping

Can you explain why clipping takes place after the illumination process in the rendering pipeline? Would it be not cheaper to clip first and do then the illumination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't actually be faster, and it would be mean a much more complex pipeline with less control and flexibility over the final image.

Conceptually, clipping creates extra vertices. When you clip a triangle, you end up with a polygon, and that means you'll need at least one extra vertex in order to turn everything into triangles again.

While many lighting computations are done now at the per-pixel level, some per-vertex setup is often necessary or desirable. It is useful to look at what reality would be if you *did* clip before you did any other per-vertex attribute computations needed for eventual per-vertex lighting.

If you were to perform lighting (and other vertex attribute) computations *after* you clipped a triangle, you'd have to have already transformed the position all the way to clip space so you know what and where to clip, and you'd also have to determine values for all attributes of all the new vertices. That means you're going to have to interpolate them, much like varying data is eventually interpolated across the surface of the triangle when fragment shading is performed.

But that means that now you have these extra computations to perform (which you're just going to perform again when you do fragment shading), *and* you have an additional vertex (at least) to run your vertex shader on. So it isn't necessarily true that clipping earlier would be more efficient.

Furthermore, many vertex attributes are specified by hand, and/or may not interpolate well. This is especially true of some of the attributes used to do some of the clever tricks used to make modern effects. That would *significantly* decrease the amount of flexibility available in the graphics pipeline to achieve interesting lighting effects or other such fancy business. Especially so with the modern programmable pipeline. That loss of flexibility would be a huge detriment, optimization or no.

Finally, a somewhat less important issue is that clipping is done in a very unusual coordinate space, and it would be fairly annoying to work in that space all the time (for lighting computations, and whatnot).

Comment: Is the same true for 3D Clipping on a frustum?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. What I wrote is about the 3D graphics pipeline, including clipping against the view frustum. Are you referring to my last paragraph? When clipping is performed (in clip space), your frustum has been transformed into what is essentially a parallelepiped in 4D space. This is a difficult to visualize space (but it has the effect of optimizing the clip computations, since you can clip against simple planes).

Comment: I just was not sure if you are speaking about the clipping on a frustum or 2d clipping.

Comment: I see. Well, if you are talking about doing illumination computations even *later* in the pipeline, once everything's been converted to 2D, that wouldn't work either for all the reasons outlined above (and in other answers), plus the fact that you'd have lost too much information.

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/ nicely visualises the effect the perspective matrix has on the geometry. Clipped, only the objects inside the frustum cube would remain (see images at roughly the middle of the article).

Answer (score 6):

Clipping happens after vertex processing, before the pixel processing stage of the graphics pipeline.  It has to take place after vertex processing for the trivial reason that clipping needs to know where the vertices are in screen space.

Clipping has nothing in particular to do with illumination.  It only takes place after illumination if you do illumination per-vertex.  But nowadays, lighting calculations are usually done per-pixel, not per-vertex.  Only the pixels within the viewport, i.e. those that survive clipping, will be shaded, so in that case illumination is done after clipping.

Comment: I should have specified that it is about 3D clipping, so why not illuminate objects that survived clipping?

Comment: @EvgenijAvstein I don't understand.  There is only one kind of clipping in the graphics pipeline, and it is 3D (conceptually, at least).  What do you mean about "objects that survived clipping"?  Object-level *culling* (not clipping) would be done even earlier, before the application even submits the geometry to the GPU.

Comment: objects that survived clipping= objects which were not clipped away

Comment: the question is why illumination everything but not just the things which are visible. Clipping not visible first and then illuminating the objects that survived clipping.

Comment: @EvgenijAvstein Because if you do that, you process more vertices and/or more vertices more often, which makes it *less* efficient, not *more*. Especially today, when most of the heavy lifting is in the fragment shading (which is post-clip) but parts of the computation still may occur at a per-vertex level.

Comment: I am just trying to find out if it conceptually would be possible! And why it is not done this way in a classic rendering pipeline.

Comment: @EvgenijAvstein You'd need two stages of vertex processing then.  One to generate the vertex positions; then clipping; then a second stage to calculate lighting. On programmable HW you'd have two vertex shaders. It would mean more complex, more expensive HW, and as Josh says you might not actually save any work because clipping can add extra vertices. Object-level culling gives you more bang-for-buck in saving work done on offscreen objects.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't necessarily do that.

In some models, lighting is per-vertex.  The problem is that you can't clip vertices until *after* they're transformed into clip space, since you have absolutely no way to know if a vertex is visible or not (aside from view frustrum clipping, which is not cheap).  So you do all per-vertex calculations in one go.  Then comes the conversion to clip space where clipping can cheaply and easily be done.  Then the clipped triangle is rasterized and the fragment/pixel shader is run.

Many newer rendering pipelines do most or all lighting calculations in the pixel shader, so it actually is done after clipping.

To cut down on the amount of vertex data processed, the application should do some form of culling.  Due to the inherent inefficiencies of clipping before hitting clip space, culling is typically by whole objects/meshes.  An object which is only partially potentially visible  will still have vertex processing done for all its vertices but at least objects which are wholly outside the view frustrum won't be sent to the GPU for processing in the first place.

In simple pseudo-code, the pipeline (including the application-side bits) is something like:

```
for each object:
  if not culled:
    for each vertex:
      run vertex shader
      convert to clip space
    for each triangle in clip space:
      clip triangle // note this is after vertices are processed
      convert to NDC space
      rasterize
    for each fragment of clipped triangles:
      do early depth test
      do early stencil test
      run pixel shader
      do alpha test, depth test, stencil test
      write depth, stencil, and blend outputs
```

Lighting traditionally was done all in vertex shaders because they're much cheaper.  A large triangle will have only 3 vertices (maybe more if clipped into a more complex polygon, though most hardware just maps all shapes into multiple trapezoids anyway) but it could have potentially thousands of fragments/pixels (maybe even millions in some cases).  Doing the computation in the pixel shader requires significantly more powerful hardware than was available when the classic rendering pipeline was defined.

Comment: NDC is 2d.Do you not clip in Clip Coord.?

Comment: Yes.  I always confuse those two.  Updating answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanx, very much!

Comment: The answer is great but it more specifies why clipping is done after transformation to clip space and not particularly why illumination should be placed before clipping. Is it possible that on this way you just would clip away the lights because they not visible from viewport/ not inside frustum?

Comment: I mentioned that in older pipelines all the lighting was done in the vertex processing stage (the vertex shader) which happens before conversion to clip space, hence it cannot be done after clipping, unless doing per-pixel lighting.  The traditional pipeline was defined long before any hardware made per-pixel lighting feasible.  Lights can and should also be culled (not clipped), and really have to be in the traditional pipelines which had a relatively low limit on the number of lights which could be applied to any one object at a time.